# Using Python to fill in a web text box with an If Statement

Tags: python, selenium, pyautogui

Hello everyone I am new to Python and I wanted to see if someone can help. I am trying to automate text input on a website. I am trying to run a code that says if the input box is empty to type 4.00 if not to press the down key. An image is provided to help understand the issue.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pyautogui





driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

login = driver.get("somesite")
sleep = time.sleep(10)

sleep

select_applications = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/header/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/button").click()
time.sleep(3)

select_app = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/header/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[33]/div/div/div[1]/span/a/img").click()

time.sleep(10)

py = pyautogui

py.moveTo('Wed.PNG')

py.move(0,35)

send_click = py.click()

if send_click = " ": 
py.hotkey("4.00)
else:
py.hotkey("down")
```

I try running the If statement but I got no results.

[image]

Comment: You have `=` instead of `==`.  Is that the way your code reads?  Does `py.click` really return one space?

Comment: Yeah that is my mistake. Putting == actually went straight to the down key even though the input box is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for a space character in the if statement.

Replace

`if send_click = " ":`

with

`if send_click == "":`

Comment: Thanks! weird thing it didn't put a "4.00" instead it press the down key. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with pyautogui but it looks to me like you're saving a value from `py.click()` which doesn't return anything, so `send_click` is empty. Try something like `driver.find_element_by_id('a').text`

Comment: I tried using selenium to find an element by id the problem is that site changes the id element as if it is randomize. So that's why I used pyautogui.

Comment: You'll need a way to locate the element, since you can't catch the element with pyautogui. If you can't use ids, try finding all the elements by class name and looping through the list

Answer (score 0):

As it's said `if send_click = " "` needs to be replaced by `if send_click = ""`
And, maybe it's a copy-paste error but there is a mistake with the identation (that's how Python understands which blocks of code are in the if statement). There should be 4 spaces before `py.hotkey("4.00)` and the same before `py.hotkey("down")`. BTW you missed quote mark in `py.hotkey("4.00)`  Now it looks like this:

```
if send_click = " ": 
py.hotkey("4.00)
else:
py.hotkey("down")
```

But should be:

```
if send_click = "": 
    py.hotkey("4.00")
else:
    py.hotkey("down")
```